# Not enough arguments error in Python, what should I do to fix this?

Tags: python

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\idlelib\full_rpg.py", line 145, in <module>
    Commands[c](p)
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\idlelib\full_rpg.py", line 57, in status
    print "%s's Level:" % (self.name, self.level)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Code line which is causing the error:

```
print "%s's Level:" % (self.name, self.level)
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: You're not serious, are you?  You can't count the number of `%`'s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide another place to put the second string.  From the python docs:

> If format requires a single argument,
>   values may be a single non-tuple
>   object. [4] Otherwise, values must be
>   a tuple with exactly the number of
>   items specified by the format string,
>   or a single mapping object (for
>   example, a dictionary).

So for your example you want:

```
"%s's Level: %s" % (self.name, self.level)
```

Assuming of course that self.level is a string.  If it's some other value type then you want to swap in the appropriate string formatting value. (%d for Integers, etc).